# Evaluate whether a column value is within a range of 2 other columns and print with awk

Tags: awk

I have two files.

File 1 (shortened):

```
1       1:135982[b38]A,G        0       12500   A       G
1       1:611317[b38]A,G        0       611317  A       G
1       1:722408[b38]G,C        0       722408  G       C
1       1:726649[b38]G,A        0       726649  G       A
```

File 2 (shortened):

```
ENSG00000223972 ENST00000456328 DDX11L1    1       11869   14409
ENSG00000223972 ENST00000450305 DDX11L1    1       11869   14409
ENSG00000227232 ENST00000488147 WASH7P     1       14404   29570
```

I want to create a new file where:

- if column 1 in file 1 matches column 4 of file 2
- AND column 4 of file 1 is within the range of columns 5 and 6 of file 2

Print column 3 of file 2 and column 2 of file 1.

Example:

For the first line of file 1, column 1 (1) matches column 4 of file 2 (also 1) AND column 4 of file 1 (12500) is >= 11869 and <= 14409, so the desired output would be:

```
DDX11L1   1:134982[b38]A,G
```

No other matches exist in this example so that would be the sole output.

How can I do this with awk?

Comment: How big are the files? Are they sorted? You're looking at O(m*n) runtime and potentially hefty memory usage if you can't optimise. This sort of thing is trivially implemented as an sql query (sqlite can read csv files).

Comment: Did not think about that. Yeah, not feasible, the files are pretty big. Thought about SQL immediately as a first resource but wanted to know if there's an awk solution.

Comment: I guess with awk you'd either have to keep the entirety of one file in memory, or re-read it over and over. Probably quite slow if it doesn't fit in memory. SQL may be fast enough untweaked; if not, creating explicit indexes may give a speedup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not awk but trivial with sqlite:

```
#!/bin/bash

# convert spaces to tabs
tr -s ' \t' '\t' <file1.raw >file1.tsv
tr -s ' \t' '\t' <file2.raw >file2.tsv

sqlite3 >output.tsv <<'EOD'
create table t1 (c1,c2,c3,c4 int,c5,c6);
create table t2 (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5 int,c6 int);
.mode tabs
.import file1.tsv t1
.import file2.tsv t2
select distinct t2.c3, t1.c2 from t1,t2
where t1.c1=t2.c4 and t1.c4 between t2.c5 and t2.c6;
EOD
```

Comment: This isn't working. For example, the first line of the output is `DDX11L1 1:135982[b38]A,G`. 135982 is not between 11869 and 14409. It's also placing the same `1:135982[b38]A,G` with other rows from the other file that have completely different coordinates as well. For context, DDX11L1 is a gene that spans a certain space, and the other thing is a mutation that is only in one place. Can't be assigned to more than one gene.

Comment: I changed the script to cast the numeric columns as integers and it seems to be working now.